# Find unique prefix and remove from array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

In Javascript, given an array of strings, how to find the unique prefix of all the strings and then remove that prefix from each string.

For example:

```
["05098701", "05012302", "0545621", "0509301"]
```

unique prefix would be "05"

resultant array would be

```
["098701", "012302", "45621", "09301"]
```

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: I think is a good question.. obviating that you have not tried to work on the solution

Comment: Yes I agree, I did try a few things. Unless you reply instantly on this site it seems people get upset. No point saying what I have tried now as someone has answered with a correct solution.

Comment: Additional the reason stated for putting on hold: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") is obviously wrong. Where in the question is any code specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search like a human does: check with one char, then with two and so on..

Then just `remove` the **prefix** from every item from the array.
You can do this using `map` method by passing a **callback** function.

```js
array = ["05098701", "05012302", "0545621", "0509301"]
function longestCommonPrefix(arr){
    // sort() method arranges array elements alphabetically
    var sortArr = arr.sort();
    
    // Get first array element    
    var arrFirstElem = arr[0];
  
    // Get the last array element length minus one
    var arrLastElem = sortArr[sortArr.length - 1]; 
    
    // Get first array element length
    var arrFirstElemLength = arrFirstElem.length; 
    
    // Set "i" incrementer to 0
    var i= 0;
    
    // while "i" is less than the length of the first array element AND
    // the first array element character position matches the last array character position
    // increment "i" by one
    while(i < arrFirstElemLength && arrFirstElem.charAt(i) === arrLastElem.charAt(i)) {
      i++;
    }
    
    //return the prefix
    return arrFirstElem.substring(0, i);
}
 

prefix = longestCommonPrefix(array);
array = array.map(function(item){
    return item.substring(prefix.length, item.length);
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Would've been nice to link to the answer you took the `findPrefix` function from, and to maybe explain why this works

Comment: @Luca, I updated my answer.

Comment: Very neat solution, thanks.